# Can I use a script alias existing in another node module's package.json?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I've created a node module that produces a `JSON` file with data from multiple APIs. It's designed to be able to save the `JSON` file into whatever directory you're within in the `CMD/Terminal`.

I'm able to run it successfully by itself as a project, but I've developed it independently from the main project that it's to be used within. It has been installed in the main project but it can only be run where it's `package.json` exists because that's where my script alias resides.

There are other node modules that need to use the `JSON` file, but once I navigate to the other modules' root directories in `CMD/Terminal` node wants to use that module's `package.json` and can't find the script alias since it doesn't exist there.

Adding the script alias to every module isn't a viable solution since the project is a prototype and constantly being added upon.

Is there a way for the relevant `package.json` to be referenced and used for the script alias regardless of where I'm running it from within the main project?

Am I going about solving this problem wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is my first question so if I've done anything wrong asking this, please let me know so I can improve. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not allow the implementing client inject the configuration for the module in question? This is a very common pattern in Node and it sounds like it fits here.

Comment: @peteb I probably should have mentioned that at this point in time it's mostly going to be a dev tool. The project is a prototype, as I did mention. Running from a CLI just gives us a way of making sure that the structure and properties of the data coincides with how the rest of the app is developed. When it becomes available it will be a 'required' module to allow objects to be created and file paths won't be a problem since it'll all be in code working in an already modular environment, so there is already a feasible solution for that. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: So in that case why don't you just pass the path to save the JSON file to as a command argument?

Comment: @peteb Another thing I should have mentioned (first question and I'm learning a ton haha). We're already doing that but since directory we want to run the CLI from is in another node module, it can't find the script alias because it doesn't exist in the package.json that node wants to check. That's why I want to reference the correct package.json

Comment: @peteb I had thought about that before asking, but the requirement was to run it from a directory and have it drop it wherever you are by just passing `%CD%` or `pwd` as the path, which makes things easy for the other devs. But maybe this is something they'll have to make a compromise on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit late but an answer nonetheless.

We ended up going for what is peteb's approach (thanks) of just using it from the appropriate package (the one with the script alias internal to it) and feeding it the external filepath through an argument.

This works because the existing structure for the arguments was:

```
npm run <script> <arg1> <filepath>
```

Although the `filepath` argument was meant to be `pwd` or `%CD%`, the output of both is a normal filepath anyway. So any filepath would theoretically work, so long as you don't run into any other problems that would warrant looking for a solution to this problem elsewhere, like the length being too long for the filesystem and whatnot.

Something that might be worth mentioning is that maybe something like this would have been better suited to an environment other than NodeJS. It doesn't look like using a script outside the package it's internal to is a possibility and it might have been better to program an external program to deal with such issues.

I'm not as proficient at NodeJS as a lot of people here on the site are, but maybe an executable containing the code that is invoked by a `.js` file could work, if that's at all possible.